# Find a pair of intergers that can be reached to another pair using 4 operations

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, logic

Given a pair of integers (eg. (x,y)). I want to find whether it is possible to convert them into another pair of integers using only the 4 operations, mentioned below, at a time for any number of times.
The operations are as follows:

```
(x,x+y)
or (x+y,y)
or (x-y,y)
or (x,x-y)
```

For eg. (4,2) can be converted to (2,6) by doing following operations:

```
(x-y,y) --- (2,2)
(x,x+y) --- (2,4)
(x,x+y) --- (2,6)
```

where as (2,2) cannot be converted to (4,4).
The answer should be a yes or a no.

Comment: if this is an assignment you should say so and show what you tried.

Comment: @1010 No not an assignment... just came across this question online.... couldn't find a logic to solve it after trying hard for 4 hours....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics (with little or no connection to programming).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claim: `(x, y)` can reach `(z, w)` if and only if `gcd(x, y) = gcd(z, w)`.

Proof: (necessary) `gcd(x, y) = gcd(x, x + y) = gcd(x + y, y) = gcd(x - y, y) = gcd(x, x - y)`. (sufficient) Reachability is symmetric. Run the Euclidean algorithm to reach `(gcd(x, y), 0)` from `(x, y)`.

Comment: It's hard to find elegant answers like this. :) But it took me a while to understand what you meant by "Reachability is symmetric".